# Why 'Quarkus' chose 'Agroal' instead of 'HikariCP' as the preferred datasource and connection pooling implementation?

Tags: java, performance, database-connection, hikaricp, quarkus

As per the [Quarkus documentation](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#configuration-reference) :

> In Quarkus, the preferred datasource and connection pooling
>   implementation is Agroal.

But, I don't see any review or comparison of 'Agroal' with the well known JDBC Connection Pooling implementation 'HikariCP'.

What makes 'Agroal' better than 'HikariCP', except that BOTH *Quarkus and Agroal* are from *RedHat*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With [Agroal](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#configuration-reference)  you can update configuration on runtime

> Configuration property overridable at runtime

While [Hikari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49301308/modify-hikari-properties-at-runtime) doesn't support it

> You can't dynamically update the property values by resetting them on the config object

Another reason is [Quarkus integration](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#configuration-reference)

> features first class integration with the other components in Quarkus, such as security, transaction management components, health metrics

Comment: Well, I would want to buy this argument that there is SOMETHING DIFFERENT, but, one probably wants to have a better performing Connection Pool instead of a dynamically configurable connection pool. I would choose this as an accepted answer, if I don't get anything with regard to 'performance' bench mark!

Comment: On the other hand, I too see an alternate work around to achieve dynamic configuration in HikariCP in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49904258/7678737). So, I'm still wondering what made 'Agroal' as the choice.

Comment: @RafiAlhamd Another reason is Quarkus integration (see update)

Comment: Looking at the number of [libraries supported by Quarkus](https://code.quarkus.io/), definitely, HikariCP could have been included. But, why _HikariCP_  was *avoided / ignored* is the curious question!

Comment: Moderators have closed this question. No choice for now.
But, need to find a way to get answer!

Comment: Happened to get answer from Quarkus Co-founder _Emmanuel Bernardin_ in Twitter. His answer: 
"Agroal is like Hikari in perf but with additional features around XA and security that we needed for Wildfly and Quarkus.". Tweet is [here](https://twitter.com/emmanuelbernard/status/1226799437722406912?s=20)

Comment: Accepted your answer.